# Внешний вид элемента JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Создал таблицу но она имеет вид сплошных линий которые разрезаются цветом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы она имела вид обычной таблицы ???

Comment: `JTable` имеет вид обычной таблицы. В каком виде она отображается в ОС это другой вопрос.

Comment: @Александр, можно это как то  изменить ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JTableExample {

    //Массив содержащий заголоки таблицы
    Object[] headers = { "Name", "Surname", "Telephone" };

    //Массив содержащий информацию для таблицы
    Object[][] data = {
        { "John", "Smith", "1112221" },
        { "Ivan", "Black", "2221111" },
        { "George", "White", "3334444" },
        { "Bolvan", "Black", "2235111" },
        { "Serg", "Black", "2221511" },
        { "Pussy", "Black", "2221111" },
        { "Tonya", "Red", "2121111" },
        { "Elise", "Green", "2321111" },
    };

    //Объект таблицы
    JTable jTabPeople;

    JTableExample() {
        //Создаем новый контейнер JFrame
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("JTableExample");
        //Устанавливаем диспетчер компоновки
        jfrm.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Устанавливаем размер окна
        jfrm.setSize(300, 170);
        //Устанавливаем завершение программы при закрытии окна
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Создаем новую таблицу на основе двумерного массива данных и заголовков
        jTabPeople = new JTable(data, headers);
        //Создаем панель прокрутки и включаем в ее состав нашу таблицу
        JScrollPane jscrlp = new JScrollPane(jTabPeople);
        //Устаналиваем размеры прокручиваемой области
        jTabPeople.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        //Добавляем в контейнер нашу панель прокрути и таблицу вместе с ней
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jscrlp);
        //Отображаем контейнер
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Создаем фрейм в потоке обработки событий
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Скриншот:
[image: Таблица]

Comment: а можно сделать так чтоб таблица имела не только заголовки колонок но и строк ???

Comment: @Vitaliy, заголовок строк это что? слева от имени еще и колонка с номером?

Comment: вы правы, именно так !!!

Comment: @Vitaliy, вот: http://base.vingrad.ru/view/2924-JTable-zagolovki-strok-i-stolbtsov